# Auto-update on Scientific-linux 6.1 64bit

Tags: yum, scientific-linux

```
yum remove PackageKit*
```

what's next?

I tried:

```
yum install yum-autoupdate
```

but I can't see any config file for it. How can I set the auto-update function* on Scientific-linux 6.1/GNOME?

*want to make the auto-update completely invisible to the GUI users!!

Does "yum-autoupdate" update packages if they fail at the GPG check?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/sysconfig/yum-autoupdate` there is the configuration of the autoupdate, you should see that `ENABLE=True` in that file, and that's mean that it enabled, and there should be more configuration that you might want to take a look at, like whether let the autoupdate to update the kernel automatically, see [here](http://scientificlinuxforum.org/index.php?showtopic=20).

you can read what packages it has updated in the `yum.log` file
see [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/16937128/dir/scientific_linux_6/com/yum-autoupdate-2-3.noarch.rpm.html) details about the package.
it should be working automatically after you have installed it, although it should be installed by default with Scientific 6.

Comment: and "yum-autoupdate" will automatically update all of my packages, and it will NOT prompts for root passwd/or any annoying pop-up message?

Comment: @LanceBaynes, that is correct. This is handled via the `/etc/cron.daily/yum-autoupdate` cronjob and is run from cron as the root user.

Comment: Note that like most cronjobs, it will send email to root@localhost, so you'll want to make sure that goes to the correct place.